# Can't Center Text For Newsletter In Mobile

Tags: html, css, newsletter

Working on an email blast and for the life of me I cannot get the text to center in mobile view. The URL is: http://strictpixel.com/clients/relevant/fbc/email/

I am referencing the top navigation, under the logo. In mobile, it slides to the left and I am not sure why.

I know this is something simple but I have been pulling my hair out for an hour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that really is a mess and you should consider refactoring.  There's no way you need all those nested tables.

However, if you plan to keep it this way, the problem is likely stemming from your HTML being invalid.  First, the `<center>` tag is dead and should not be used.  Second, you break the flow of your table structure beginning after the comment I inserted below:

```
            <p class="template-label">469-952-6404</p></td>
            <td class="expander"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>

<!-- You can't start the new table below here without first either
opening a new <td> or closing the <tr> and <table> that is open!!  -->

<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper">
            <table class="twelve columns" style="background-color:#f1f5f8;vertical-align:center;">
...
```

My best guess is that you missed opening up the next `<td>` tag just before that `table` begins.

Use an online HTML validator to help you find where your table structure is broken.  Something like http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html may prove useful.

Comment: I am terrible with tables, which is why it is probably a complete disaster. HTML5 & CSS3 I am just fine. Just trying to center the text that is all. I did close the </tr> and </table> and still can't seem to get it to work. I had the <center> tag in there as I am trying just about everything I can think of, lol.

The code is updated live on the server if there is any chance I can get your assistance again!

Comment: @MichaelFroseth Okay what is it _supposed_ to look like?  Let's start there. Are those images supposed to be next to each other?  Because each of those images are over 500px and they are showing up side by side, so your .container table width of 584px is irrelevant because the images are pushing it out wider.  This could be why your centering is broken.

Comment: It should look exactly how it is. The only thing that is looking not how it should is the navigation buttons at the top. Luxury Lines, Online Catalog, etc... Those are aligning to left when viewed on mobile, when I'd like them to center, as they are on desktop.

The images are meant to scale. I am taking them from a different section of the project. Ones we used on a homepage. And to answer your question, they are meant to stack next to each other and on top. We wanted a full bleed effect.

Comment: You using Chrome?  On Firefox, it's all messed up: http://awesomescreenshot.com/09a4v614d2

Your problems are probably bigger than you think as the way those tables will render really depends on what is being used to view them - not only which browser, but which device (home computer vs tablet vs iPhone vs Android).

I suggest you look into using a service to build your mailer.  There are lots of very moderately priced services you can use, often for under $20. Some examples here: http://tinyurl.com/oo3k3ga If you really insist on doing it yourself, you should use a responsive template.

Comment: Do you have a sugestion for a responsive template? Similar to that?

Comment: @MichaelFroseth You can find hundreds of them for under $20 here: http://themeforest.net/category/marketing/email-templates  I would sort by "Best Rated" and then look at the number of sales to find templates that have been put through to test and still achieved a high rating.  Look through them, check out the "Live Preview" which features a button to see what it would look like on mobile.  When find one you like just replace the content with your content and you'll be sending out high quality email blasts in no time.

Comment: I ended up using the ZURB framework and it worked perfectly. Not sure why I didn't think of this in the first place. Here is the updated email blast: http://strictpixel.com/clients/relevant/fbc/email/

Does that display better for you? Just can't seem how to get the full bleed effect on those 4 images. Any idea how to remove that white space? I removed padding/margins from the <tr> elements but nothing.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks much better!  But there is still some alignment issues to deal with. Note that the top image is 596px wide, while the ones below are 292px wide, adding up to 584px of image width so that is where (at least some of) your white space is coming from.  Gotta run, but I will check back later tonight and see if you got it going.  If you are so inclined, go ahead and accept the answer so I can get reputation credit. Good luck!

Comment: To remove the rest of that whitespace, add **style="border-collapse: collapse;"** to each of the two tables and add **style="width: 298px;"** to each of the 4 *img* tags. That should do the trick.